# jquery ui - referencing dropped element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

So I know that if an element is droppable, then you can set an option like:

```
drop: function(){
 alert('something was dropped');
}
```

but how can I set it so I can reference the element dropped onto it, so I could do something like this:

```
drop: function(){
 alert(elementId + ' was dropped');
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
drop: function(event, ui) {
    alert($(ui).attr("id") + " was dropped");
}
```